# Kinect SDK 1.6 and Joint.ScaleTo method

Tags: wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using Kinect SDK 1.6, and I'm following the *Skeleton Tracking Funamentals* tutorial of *Windows Kinect Quickstart Series*, available [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals).

Even if these tutorials have been made for SDK 1.0, **all was going pretty well until I followed the instructions to map the position of my hands on a custom-sized window (say 1280x720)**.

Dan Fernandez is using the following line of code to achieve this

```
    private void ScalePosition(FrameworkElement element, Joint joint)
    {
        // Convert the value to X/Y;
        Joint scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(1280, 720);

        ....
    }
```

Well, the method `ScaleTo` is not a custom function, it should be provided in the Kinect SDK, but according to my editor, there's no such method. I can't locate it, and I think it might have been moved/renamed/whatever since SDK 1.0.

Just to make sure everything is in order, here is my `using` list, everyithing else (Skeleton tracking etc.) is working, so I really can't figure it out

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;
```

I can give further details about my code on request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the correct reference to Coding4Fun, you are actually just missing this:

```
using Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf;
```

at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this SDK in combination with the newest Microsoft SDK if you need `ScaleTo()`:

http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/

It's open source so you could just as well use their code and have your own `ScaleTo()`.

Remember to add the correct using directive:

```
using Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf;
```

[how to scale joints using the new Kinect SDK in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413200/how-to-scale-joints-using-the-new-kinect-sdk-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Scaling is part of the Coding4Fun library, available here:
http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/

Alternatively, you can write your own scaling.

Something like this will create a "hit box" of tracking for right hand, centered around the right shoulder, and will scale it to whatever the resolution of your primary screen is.

```
double xScaled = (rightHand.Position.X - leftShoulder.Position.X) / ((rightShoulder.Position.X - leftShoulder.Position.X) * 2) * SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
double yScaled = (rightHand.Position.Y - head.Position.Y) / (rightHip.Position.Y - head.Position.Y) * SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

Here is another example of a function that scales the Kinect coordinates to the screen resolution:

```
private static double ScaleY(Joint joint)
{
    double y = ((SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 0.4) * -joint.Position.Y) + (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 2);
    return y;
}

private static void ScaleXY(Joint shoulderCenter, bool rightHand, Joint joint, out int scaledX, out int scaledY)
{
    double screenWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

    double x = 0;
    double y = ScaleY(joint);

    // if rightHand then place shouldCenter on left of screen
    // else place shouldCenter on right of screen
    if (rightHand)
    {
        x = (joint.Position.X - shoulderCenter.Position.X) * screenWidth * 2;
    }
    else
    {
        x = screenWidth - ((shoulderCenter.Position.X - joint.Position.X) * (screenWidth * 2));
    }


    if (x < 0)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    else if (x > screenWidth - 5)
    {
        x = screenWidth - 5;
    }

    if (y < 0)
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    scaledX = (int)x;
    scaledY = (int)y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had already downloaded the Coding4Fun library and added the reference (the WPF-related one) but it does not work..

Comment: Your `using` code block above does not include a reference to it.  Did you forget to add it as a reference or punch into the `using` section?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can fix the error using this dll file


http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/releases/view/76271
```