# how to scale joints using the new Kinect SDK in C#

Tags: c#, kinect

Since `ScaleTo()` has been removed from the new Kinect SDK how is the scaling going to be done with the new SDK???

Comment: have you saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313005/kinect-sdk-1-6-and-joint-scaleto-method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit: http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/

Download the library, include it in your project's resources and then add a reference to it in your `using` statements.  After you do that, you will have a `scaleTo()` function for individual joints.  e.g., `rightHand.scaleTo(640, 480)`.

The library website has some information on using it.  You can also find more information on using the library in the Skeleton Tracking Fundamentals post at Channe9: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals